# Where can I find the source of libsystem_c.dylib?

Tags: ios, c, standard-library

I have a strange line in my stacktrace that I want to investigate further:

```
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa272dc free + 168
```

If I understand correctly, libsystem_c is C standard library. Is the version used in the iOS open-sourced? Where can I get that source?

Comment: That seems to be a standard call to free, i.e. freeing allocated memory.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's why I want to look at the body of free() function in the standard library that Apple uses on iOS — to determine which kind of error it may be.

Comment: Why don't you look higher up the stack trace to see what's causing your call to free?

Comment: @Daniel I'm trying to understand that too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543019/what-of-this-c-sharp-code-can-result-in-a-call-to-free-in-compiled-form

Comment: Ah, ok. I still think looking at the source code for free (which I doubt you will find, atleast for iOS) is going to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be more specific, I think it is hosted here:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/

Answer (score 0):

For someone who may need answer

You can find OSX sources at
[https://opensource.apple.com/](https://opensource.apple.com)

Comment: I don't think that it contains sources for libsystem.