# What of this C# code can result in a call to free() in compiled form?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm investigating a stack trace of a compiled Unity C# code. It results in an error inside the standard C free() function. The frame where the free() is called is a pretty simple method, which looks like this:

```
void Method()
{
    SomeOtherMethod();

    if (StaticClass.StaticProperty == SomeMethod())
    {
        StaticClass.StaticProperty = 0;

        StopCoroutine("Coroutine name");

        if (m_privateField < CONSTANT)
            YetAnotherMethod();
        else
            AndOneMoreMethod();
    }
}
```

It seems to me that all I do here is calling other code and doing very basic equality comparisons and conditions; however, there is no other frames between this code and free(). What part of this could possibly call it?

Here's this part of the stack trace symbolized by xcode:

```
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa5be90 _sigtramp + 40
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aa272dc free + 168
13  dev                             0x002ea644 ___lldb_unnamed_function10628$$dev + 176
```

[I was able to determined that line 13 is this method with the help of atoc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539907/c-sharp-part-of-ios-crash-log-stack-trace-doesnt-make-any-sense)

Comment: You do not show the stack trace so it's not easy to answer.

Comment: Why don't you disassemble to IL and see for yourself?

Comment: @poupou Added stack trace.

Comment: @RoyDictus if I'm not mistaken, in Unity C# is compiled to native, not IL.

Comment: Maybe one of the called methods was inlined.

Comment: StopCoroutine can free the associated memory.

Comment: @Heisenbug I thought so too. However, StopCoroutine doesn't seem to cause this bug anywhere but this. It's possible that this coroutine isn't started at the time of this code's execution — but in all other situations like this it doesn't result in any crashes.